# MVC, passing classes between controller and view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a scenario as follows; a "Survey" contains a list of type "Question"; "Question" is made up of an id and a string called "Text".  Here are the class definitions:

```
public class Survey
{
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public Survey()
    {
        this.Questions = new List<Question>();
    }
}

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public int OwningSurveyId { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to link from the page for a specific Survey to create a new Question (which works fine), but when the Question form is submitted I want to do two things; 1) ensure that the OwningSurveyId is set correctly, and 2) add the Question to Survey.Questions List.

I am open to any solution to get this functionality - the approach I've taken may not be the best.  What I decided to do was pass the Survey object into the Create form for the Question, so that when the form is submitted, the form contains both objects, and so I can perform both tasks above (1 & 2) correctly.

I set up the Create Question page in the QuestionController as follows:

```
// GET: /Question/Create

    public ActionResult Create(Survey OwningSurvey)
    {
        return View(OwningPulse);
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Pulse OwningPulse, Question NewQuestion)
    {
        ModelState["OwningSurveyId"].Errors.Clear();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            OwningPulse.Questions.Add(NewQuestion);
            db.Questions.Add(NewQuestion);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Survey");
        }

        return View(OwningSurvey);
    }
```

and the Create.cshtml file for the Question has the following:

```
@model MoodTool.Interface.Models.Survey

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";

var Question = new MoodTool.Interface.Models.Question();
Question.OwningPulseId = Model.SurveyId;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Question", "{NewQuestion}", FormMethod.Post, new { NewQuestion = Question }))
{... code follows
```

The problem I have is that the value of the "Model" in the .cshtml file is null, and therefore the page crashes.  The value of OwningSurvey in the Create method of the Question controller ("GET" version) is also null.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?  I realise that I'm probably doing something either majorly wrong (design patterns), or have made a simple syntax error, but I'm new to MVC and going round in circles.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you loading the model for the survey you added the questions to in the Survey Action?  If not then that is why your model is null.  That's just my guess based on what I see here.  RedirectToActions don't load the model so you'll have to put it into TempData and reload it in the redirected action.

Part II

In the first part you are creating the question and redirecting to the index action for survey.

```
 OwningPulse.Questions.Add(NewQuestion);
 db.Questions.Add(NewQuestion);
 db.SaveChanges();
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Survey");
```

Once in the index action you need to reload the survey in which you placed the question in the first place and load it into a model to pass to the view.  Using lavriks method above by passing the id to the action method you could then get that survey from the db and pass it to the view in the model defined for the view.

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
         // assuming you have some built in functionality to retrieve the survey information from the db through the constructor given an id
        Survey s1 = new survey(id);  

        // some of this is pseudo code, assumes you have a model defined called survey for the view using it
        // Return view with model.
        return View( "Survey" , s1 );
    }
```

When I spoke of tempdata instead of passing an ID to the action method and looking it up again in the action method for your view you could store the object in tempdata

```
     // save data to survey in teh create action method
     TempData["survey"] = survey
```

Then in the default index action method for the Survey recall the survey out of tempdata and send it to the view.

```
     Survey s1 = (Survey)Tempdata["survey"];
     return View ("Survey", s1);
```

Again some of this is pseudocode and not totally complete but it should point you in the right direction.  Both approaches have their up and down side but depending on the app, size of the objects, how many people are hitting hte pages etc you could go with either or.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'm afraid that I don't understand though; would you mind expanding your answer a little?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this method (TempData) has solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the best approach here is Post-Redirect-Get pattern. You just post the Question form with survey id. In controller you can try to read survey by id and check if it exists. Then add question and save survey. And redirect to Survey GET action for example. It will be shown including newly added question. 
Moreover you'll post only question here and survey id - you don't need anyhing more here. You will not change Survey by posting some unneccessary data - so it's a bit safer also.

EDIT.

For example.

```
// GET: /Question/Create
public ActionResult Create(int surveyId)
{
    return View(new Question(){OwningSurveyId = surveyId });
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Question newQuestion)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //I've never used EntityFramework so just a pseudo code here
        var survey = db.Surveys.Get(newQuestion.OwningSurveyId);
        if(survey != null)
        {
            survey.Questions.Add(newQuestion);
            db.Surveys.Save(survey); 
            db.SaveChanges();
            //If you want to open specific survey, 
            //you can pass it's Id to read it in Survey index action
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Survey", {Id = survey.Id});
        }
    }

    return View(newQuestion);
}
```

And view for create question

```
@model MoodTool.Interface.Models.Question

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Question", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OwningSurveyId)
     @Html.EditorFor(x => x.QuestionText)
       //etc.
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I am using a 'RedirectToAction' in the Create method already; can you please give an example of how I could use the PRG pattern to solve this problem?  Thanks

Comment: Great, thanks.  I have tried your method as well, it works great!  I went with the TempData as it persists and I can use it later, but you did solve the question so I feel bad I can't put them both as answers :-)